# Custom navigation drawer with activity?

Tags: android

I have the following template for make custom list views in activity.

How I can use this template to set the `listviews` inside `navigationDrawer` element of Android?

Is it possible to inflate `navigationDrawer` with an activity?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlist);

    context = this;

    CheckboxListAdapter adapter = new CheckboxListAdapter(getLayoutInflater());
    this.getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

    this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                if(position == 0)
                {   


                }                   


            };
        });

}

 public class CheckboxListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

    private LayoutInflater inflator;

    public CheckboxListAdapter(LayoutInflater inflator) {
        super();
        this.inflator = inflator;

    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(position == 0)
        {

        }else if(position == 1)
        {                   

        }
        else if(position == 2)
        {

        }


        return view;
    }

    public int getCount() {

        return 3;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: [The page has also a ready to run sample app.](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link. [http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html.) 
It uses ListView for the Drawer.

Basically you are expected to do the following

1. Extend `Activity` instead of `ListActivity.`
2. DrawerLayout should be the root view of your layout.

   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
           <ListView android:id="@+id/my_drawer"
       ...  />
   </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
3. Thus, replace the `this.getListView()` with reference to `ListView` found in the Drawer.